# Re-map linked tables in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am a relative novice with Access and starting from scratch with coding, so be gentle.

I have an Access 2010 database with dozens of linked tables based on .txt files. Sometimes the database moves, the source files move or the file server just gets re-named. In these events I am looking for a simple way for a user of the database to remap and refresh the linked tables. Ideally, it would be user prompted, i.e. the user pushes a button to refresh from a navigation form or something. Then, the system prompts for the new folder location. The folder location would house all of the necessary files, so it only needs to be selected one time. Once selected, all linked tables should remap and refresh with the user getting an error or success message.

I have seen a lot of these questions asked, but they seem to be in older versions of Access or it is not asking for a user prompt or for a user to browse for the new path.

Thanks.

Comment: this'd be a major reason to sit back, re-evaluate the design, and conclude it's crap and start using a real database, without depending on external files which apparently are movable at-whim.

Comment: Thanks. There are many reasons for doing this. We have a fairly sophisticated database and a dedicated dev team. However, they are not agile, nor are we guaranteed stable internet access since we are consultants traveling all the time to remote areas. So, this is a local, slimmed down version of the Oracle DB with just essentials for us to use on the road. It is movable because I want to develop it on a file server, but then deploy it to each of the individuals on my team each day with updated data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with Marc B that this seems like a very oddly constructed database you could use the following code the manually link the tables again to the proper location. You would need to work this into a system that can loop through all tables and do them all one by one or adjust this code to do that automatically.  But you may want to just rethink your system.

```
Function SetTableLinkPath(strTableName As String, strTablePath As String)

    If Nz(strTableName, "") <> "" And Nz(strTablePath, "") <> "" Then
        Dim cdb As DAO.Database

        Set cdb = CurrentDb

        cdb.TableDefs(strTableName).Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strTablePath
        cdb.TableDefs(strTableName).RefreshLink

        MsgBox "Table link for " & strTableName & " has been successfully set to the path: " & strTablePath & "."
    Else
        MsgBox "You must enter a valid Table path and name!"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you Newd. I will work in a loop function to handle all of them.

Comment: No problem, and after your explanation in your comments I can see why this could be useful in your situation.